# Writing Specific Fields to XLS

Tags: arcpy, excel, fields-attributes

I would like to write only specific fields to an excel export. My current script is written as this:

```
fc = r"C:/Users/maps/table.xls"
xlsLocation = r"C:/Users/maps"
xlsOutputName = "SanFrancisco"
xlsPath = xlsLocation + '\\' + xlsOutputName + '.xls'
keepFields = ["name", "UID", "notes", "records", "surveyname"]

# I wrote the following, but it returned error 999999: Error executing function. I assume this maybe because the listfield function can't read xls?

fields = arcpy.ListFields(xlsPath)
dropFields = [x.name for x in fields if x.name not in keepFields]
print "Deleting extraneous fields in xls"
arcpy.DeleteField_management (xlsPath, dropFields)
```

Not certain about how to proceed. Our projects requires xls, so no other format can be considered. The excel file contains over 50 fields. I am using python 2.7

Comment: I'd start with [Excel To Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/excel-to-table.htm)  For this question recording your version of ArcGIS will be important.

Comment: Beware your case! if x.name not in keepFields should be either upper() or lower() - python is a case sensitive language, *name* is not the same as *Name*. Rather than delete field make a feature layer and use a field_info object to restrict the fields you don't want http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000. Your error is probably because you're trying to remove a required field (like OID or Shape).

Comment: I think problem is that you are trying to treat an XLS as a table.  Try using Delete Field from its tool dialog to delete a field from an XLS direct.  I don't think you will be able to.  I would not expect ListFields to be able to read its fields either.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us anything about your feature-layers (where the data is coming from). So far, it seems you are merely trying to manipulate an xls file via arcpy.

You cant use `ListFields` on a xls. Use it on your feature-layer or geodatabase table, then sort out the fields you don't need, and THEN export to xls. Depending on your ArcMap version you may find the [Table to Excel](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000054000000) Tool in your conversion toolbox. Otherwise [download](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f3d91b8f852042e289e09a7ec8342431) it first.

You are trying to remove the fields from an xls, but you need to do that when you export the table from your feature-layer/shapefile, and not when the xls is already written.